# Grab contents of a webpage in GWT

Tags: gwt

Let's say that I have a link to a webpage that contains some text.  What's the easiest way to grab this text to process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, I don't think it's possible to make a request from the client js to grab the text from a url with a different domain.

It is possible to make requests to load json. [This link](http://code.google.com/intl/ja/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/Xsite.html) describes how.

Basically, the steps are:

- Embed a  tag in the GWT page
- after GWT page is initialized, update
  the script tag's src to load remote
  url
- remote url returns some json data
  padded inside a callback javascript
  function such as:
  callback({blah:foo})

So, you're only option may be writing a method on the server side that loads the url, gets the text. You could then call this method from gwt client using normal rpc technique.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming same origin: use the ["RequestBuilder" class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/index.html?overview-summary.html).

If you are trying to grab a webpage from a different origin, then it obviously won't work.